# Microsoft office.js Excel add-in - is it possible to detect excel SAVE action performed by user?

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, office365api

I am using Office.js API and javascript/react.js for an Excel Add-in and wants to perform an action (execute a function) when the active worksheet/workbook is **saved by user**. 
below is the code used to listen save action:

```
Office.initialize = () => {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");             
        context.workbook.load(["save"]);                                                  
        context.sync().then(() => {
        context.workbook.save(Excel.SaveBehavior.prompt);
        //OR
        context.workbook.save(Excel.SaveBehavior.save);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.debugInfo);
    });
}
```

Comment: Document Saving, opening, printing, etc events are not available in Office.js. However the feature has been requested a lot on officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general.

Comment: @lumpenstein, thanks for your reply. Can you please let me excel close event can we detect?